# How do I turn off "Arrange dashboard tiles in a single column" in looker?

Tags: python, looker

I'm doing a mass scheduling service and for the life of me I can't turn off "Arrange dashboard tiles in a single column" in python. if it was just 1, I would go in and change it, but I have 1k+ and would like have this as false in my python script.

```
from xmlrpc.client import boolean
from looker_sdk import methods, models40
import looker_sdk
sdk = looker_sdk.init40("../looker.ini")

def create_simple_schedule(dashboard_id:int,user_id:int,schedule_title:str, format:str, email:str,type:str, message:str, crontab:str, filters_string:str):
    schedule = sdk.create_scheduled_plan(
body=models40.WriteScheduledPlan(name=schedule_title, dashboard_id=dashboard_id, user_id=user_id, run_as_recipient= True,  include_links=False,crontab=crontab, filters_string=filters_string, scheduled_plan_destination = [models40.ScheduledPlanDestination(format=format, apply_formatting=True, apply_vis=True, address=email,  type=type, message=message,)]))

create_simple_schedule(505,321,"title", "assembled_pdf", "my.fake.email@email.com", "email", "Hello", "0 6 5 * *","my filters")
```

[image]